# How can I tell gradle to use the newest library, snapshot or no?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, aar

I have a personal maven repo setup with the following structure:

```
root (accessible via http)
 - maven/
   - com/
     - mycompany/
       - core/
         - core/
           - 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT/
           - 1.1.0/
           - maven-metadata.xml
           - maven-metadata.xml.md5
           - maven-metadata.xml.sha1
```

Now, inside of the `1.1.0` and `1.1.0-SNAPSHOT` directories are the appropriate libraries, in aar form (I'm running on android). Inside of the project for which I want to utilize this library's build.gradle file, I have the following:

```
repositories {                                                                  
    maven { url 'http://builds.myserver.net/maven' }

}
dependencies {
      compile 'com.mycompany.core:core:1.1.0@aar'                       
}
```

Now, when I do a `./gradlew --refresh-dependencies`, it, of course, downloads the version `1.1.0` (not `1.1.0-SNAPSHOT`). If I change the dependency to be `compile 'com.mycompany.core:core:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'`, then it finds the appropriate SNAPSHOT. This is all fine and dandy, but what I really want is to be able to specify the NEWEST version. So, for example, if I had a version of the library `1.2.0`, it should find that, or `1.2.0-SNAPSHOT`, it should find that. I've tried `compile 'com.mycompany.core:core:1.1.0+@aar'`, but that still only finds the version `1.1.0`, not `1.1.0-SNAPSHOT`, and, if I have `1.2.0` or `1.2.0-SNAPSHOT`, it doesn't find those, either.

I'm wondering what the heck the purpose of the `+` is if it doesn't find the most recent libraries in the repo. Does it only track off of the first version number? Or somehow off of the date?

**EDIT:**

As suggested, I tried making my `build.gradle` reference `latest.integration`, as in: `compile 'com.mycompany.core:core:latest.integration' (I also removed the`@aar`), but when I run`./gradlew --refresh-dependencies`, I see the following:

```
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration
> Could not resolve com.mycompany.core:core:latest.integration.
     Required by:
         my-project:MyApp:unspecified
      > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

I'm wondering if this is due to an older version of gradle. It looks like we're using:

```
mustafar scottjohnson$ ./gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.12
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2014-04-29 09:24:31 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     a831fa866d46cbee94e61a09af15f9dd95987421

Groovy:       1.8.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
Ivy:          2.2.0
JVM:          1.6.0_65 (Apple Inc. 20.65-b04-466.1)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.10.1 x86_64
```

It appears that when I run it with `--info`, it is still looking for `1.2.0` (rather than `1.2.0-SNAPSHOT`:

```
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://builds.myserver.net/maven/com/mycompany/core/core/1.2.0/core-1.2.0.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://builds.myserver.net/maven/com/mycompany/core/core/1.2.0/core-1.2.0.aar]
```

Comment: When you use `1.1.+` or `1.2.+`, do you get what you want? From [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14987308/115145), it appears that Gradle may use [Ivy version matcher syntax](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/trunk/settings/version-matchers.html), which may give you other ideas of syntax to try.

Comment: Let me try that, and I'll let you know. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

`"com.mycompany.core:core:latest.integration"` should do the trick. (`"com.mycompany.core:core:+"` will have the same effect in some Gradle versions, but will only match releases (i.e. non-snapshots) in other Gradle versions. A safe way to get the latest release version is `latest.release`.) `@aar` shouldn't be necessary (assuming a POM with correct packaging type is published) and will disable transitive dependency resolution, which is typically not what you want.

Comment: Sorry for the late response... holidays and all. ;) I've edited my question above with an exception that I'm seeing when I try to use `latest.integration`.

Comment: I'd have to see the `--stacktrace`. Try with the latest Gradle version.